# How to add more columns to sessions function in scapy

Tags: scapy

i like the function pkt.sessioins() in scapy, how i can add more columns to this table:

```
x.sessions()
{'TCP 10.0.2.15:32896 > 173.194.34.159:80': <PacketList: TCP:11 UDP:0 ICMP:0 Other:0>,
```

Thanks

Comment: You mean you want more data about each session?

Answer (score 0):

To add more information you would need to define your own "session extractor" function and pass it to the `.sessions()` method.

But you cannot add information about the whole session (like total data size) since this is known only when the whole session has been read.

A quick way to add total data size, for example, would be to create your own `sessions()` function (adapted from the original `PacketList.sessions()` method:

```
def sessions(plist, session_extractor=None):
    if session_extractor is None:
        def session_extractor(p):
            sess = "Other"
            if 'Ether' in p:
                if 'IP' in p:
                    if 'TCP' in p:
                        sess = p.sprintf("TCP %IP.src%:%r,TCP.sport% > %IP.dst%:%r,TCP.dport%")
                    elif 'UDP' in p:
                        sess = p.sprintf("UDP %IP.src%:%r,UDP.sport% > %IP.dst%:%r,UDP.dport%")
                    elif 'ICMP' in p:
                        sess = p.sprintf("ICMP %IP.src% > %IP.dst% type=%r,ICMP.type% code=%r,ICMP.code% id=%ICMP.id%")
                    else:
                        sess = p.sprintf("IP %IP.src% > %IP.dst% proto=%IP.proto%")
                elif 'ARP' in p:
                    sess = p.sprintf("ARP %ARP.psrc% > %ARP.pdst%")
                else:
                    sess = p.sprintf("Ethernet type=%04xr,Ether.type%")
            return sess
    sessions = defaultdict(lambda: [plist.__class__(), 0])
    for p in plist.res:
        sess = session_extractor(plist._elt2pkt(p))
        sessions[sess][0].append(p)
        sessions[sess][1] += len(p)
    return dict(sessions)
```

Each **value** (the **keys** do not change) in the resulting `dict` is a two elements `list`, the first one being the `PacketList` object, just as with the `.sessions()` method, and the second one the total data size for the session.